# Getting No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fabric, amazon-rds

Why am I getting "No hosts found"? Following is my code and how do I fix it?

```
def upload_log(self, instance_name, logfile):
    ''' Uploads an RDS log to S3 given the instance_name and the log file
    name. '''

    log = self._get_log_file(instance_name, logfile)
    key = '/'.join([instance_name, log.log_filename])
    try:
        print r'uploading logfile {} to s3://{}'.format(log.log_filename,
                                                        key)
        self._write_key(key, log.data)
        print 'uploaded logfile: {}'.format(key)
    except Exception as e:
        os.chdir("/LogFiles/")

#Getting No hosts found when it comes in except block somewhere here-->

        command1 = "rds-download-db-logfile pgd-1 --log-file-name error/{0} > {0}".format(log.log_filename)
        os.system(command1)
        command2 = "s3cmd put {} s3://rds-logproduction/pgd-1/error/".format(log.log_filename)
        os.system(command2)
```

I am trying to upload the log files from RDS to S3.

So, when it asks for the host name, I pass in 'us-west-2.amazonaws.com' and after that I get

```
fabric.exceptions.NetworkError: Name lookup failed for us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The S3 hostname should be `s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: It's not an answer? The hostname he provided is incorrect and I provided the correct one.